# android interaction internal

Tags: android

i have this code  and i don't understand how can I make both interact between them

I know that Activities are designed to represent a single screen of my application, while Fragments are designed to be reusable UI layouts with logic embedded inside of them.

Comment: Your question as it exists now is very vague.  To get a meaningful answer, I think you need to restore at least some of the code that you deleted (preferably just a part that really illustrates the problem) and explain specifically what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this method.

```
public void addFragmenListener(OnFragmentInteractionListener ofil2) {
    myListener = ofil2;
}
```

Therefore, you don't need to do this

```
fragment.addFragmenListener(this);
```

Reason being is that `onAttach` already takes care of that for you.

---

As for how the Fragment interacts with the Activity, it is simply done by calling this anywhere in the Fragment class

```
myListener.onFragmentInteraction("Some Message");
```

Which is passed back to this method in the Activity

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(String message) {
    Log.d("MAIN", message);

}
```